# How to scroll down Twitch page using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitch

I have been stuck on this for a while and can't figure this out. How do I scroll down this specific page, it seems to not find the scroll bar.

Link: https://www.twitch.tv/directory/category/counter-strike-global-offensive/clips?featured=false&range=24hr

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried to use

```py
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```